# Discord bot doesn't respond to message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have put `MessageContent` in intents, but it does not work. Here is what I've tried:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const logger = require('winston');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],

});
const token = "69420"


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot do online')

});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === "hello") {
        msg.channel.send("helo man")
    }

})

bot.login(token)
```

Comment: Have you also enabled the message content intent inside your developer portal?

Comment: If you are working with discord.js@v12+ I recommend you to move on discord.js@13+ or 
 14+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using discord.js@13.xx.x+, you have to use `messageCreate` event, not `message`.

```js
bot.on('ready', () => { // when the bot is ready and online
    console.log('bot is now online!')
});

bot.on('messageCreate', message => { // when there is a message sent
    if (message.content === "ping") {
        message.channel.send("pong!")
    }
})
```

`message` is for discord.js@12+

`messageCreate` is for discord.js@13+

Make sure you have message content privillaged intent **turned on**, on [Discord developers portal](https://discord.com/developers/apps)

Also, **remember to not share your token anywhere**, and put it in a safe file.